# Headsets do not pair with bluetooth (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I've just made a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. Everything seemed fine unless I realized that in nautilus I'm not able to pair any of my bluetooth headset Philips SHB4140 nor Wesc pisont black BC

The curious thing is I had access to Wesc pisont black BC a moment ago and it is not pairing anymore.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I had this problem before, in a fresh install, just did a reboot. also check if your Bluetooth is enabled

Comment: [Edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/682173/edit) to also include `pactl list short | grep discover` thanks

Comment: I fully read https://goo.gl/buoOcx which is out of date

Comment: And this on http://goo.gl/fgrNNa but my problem is I cannot see any headset candidate to pairing. I'm pretty sure this was working some weeks ago....

Comment: When I have a look at https://goo.gl/1yiK5E and issue the command laurent06000@PC-DE-LDP:~$ sudo modprobe snd-bt-sco
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-bt-sco not found. Please what next

Answer (score 0):

Hello sorry for inconvenience but i manage to pair my  [Philips SHB 7150](http://goo.gl/NltRRT)

It was just a mismatch in the button pressed. You have to press until the white light is flashing.

The user manual is there [User manual](http://goo.gl/ueJbTn)

Hope this can help others with the same device

Comment: I can also pair another bluetooth headset WESC Piston BT Black which works very well. Description is  here http://goo.gl/1f63wp.